# Suppose the two probability measures on $\mathbb R_+$ are ordered on any $[0,t)$. Are they also ordered on Borel sets?

Tags: probability

Suppose the two probability measures $\mu(\cdot)$ and $\nu(\cdot)$ on $(\mathbb R_+, \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+))$ are such that $\mu([0,t))\leq \nu([0,t))$ for all $t>0$. Is it true that $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$ for $A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)$? Any references?

Comment: If $A=[t,\infty)$ your ordering goes the other way.

Comment: Thank you. You are right.

Comment: If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures and $\mu(A) \le \nu(A)$ for all $A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mu = \nu$.

Comment: For probability measures the hypothesis can be weakened to $\mu (K) \leq \nu(K)$ for every compact set $K$.